# Object "mydata" not found error in rmd

Tags: r, knitr

when I run the following code in R Studio, it works (produce the graph). But, when I knit the document to HTML it gives an error as: object "mydata" not found. How can I fix it?

```
mydata <- read.csv("impt5.csv") 

get("mydata")

xyplot(gdppc ~ human + unemp +inv+indust | class, data = mydata, 
             auto.key = list(x = .85, y = .035, corner = c(0, 0)), 
   layout = c(4,1), main = "Per capita gdp by class")
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `get()` call there? You may want to show the code chunk of your document

Comment: `get()` is used as a trial to fix the problem. Sorry, I forgot to remove it from the codes. You can ignore  `get()`

Comment: Remove `get` then. Put `getwd()` before `read.csv` and see if working directory is where you think it is for this chunk.

Answer (score 1):

1. set the working directory to the folder containing your CSV file.
2. You might want to create a R markdown file instead (.rmd), this is a easy to create an HTML document,or for any other format you want.

Please look into the R markdown help document.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, use:

`mydata <- read.csv(paste0(getwd(),"impt5.csv"))`

`paste0()` is the `paste()` function with `sep=" "`

Comment: Why do you think that this answers the question? By default, "if [the argument `file` of `read.csv`] does not contain an *absolute* path, the file name is *relative* to the current working directory" (from `?read.csv`).

Comment: What you say is true. I felt that adding some explicit code might help a newbie e.g. the fact that you can use `paste()` as a filename. This question is after all aimed more at newbies. Or have I missed your point?

Comment: Sorry, I was not very precise in the previous comment. While the error is very likely related to the working directory, I wouldn't expect that appending the path to the WD is useful because by default, file names are resolved relative to the current WD. So while knowing how to use `paste` is definitely important for newbies, I don't think it helps in this specific case.